# How to make Markdown ignore <script> statements, if not under Code Samples?

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, strip-tags, pagedown

I use [the same JavaScript Markdown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) as here on Stack Overflow. My problem is this:

I have a textfield:

```
<textarea id="markdown" class="markdown"></textarea>
```

And on keyup I do this event and logic:

```
 var converter = new Markdown.Converter();

 $('textarea#markdown').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().length >= 1) {
        var html = $(this).val().replace(/<script(.*?)>(.*?)<\/script>/gi, '');

        $('div#markdown_preview').html( converter.makeHtml( html ) );
    } else {
        $('div#markdown_preview').html('Your Markdown will be previewed in here...');
    }
});
```

As you see, with my Regular Expression, I strip all the `<script>` statements, so something like:

```
<code> <script></script> </code>
```

Won't work either. How can I make this working, same like here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Just a note, you can do what you're doing in that keyup by simply using the sanitizing converter instead, and you don't need to create a new converter on every keyup. This won't fix your script in code issue though

Comment: yes, I've seen it now in the docs.. I will publiish the answer myself, might help someone!

Comment: Did it actually fix the script-in-code issue? i didn't see anything in Markdown.Sanitizer.js that would fix that.

Comment: @KevinB, yes kevin, Sanitizer is the solver of this problem-situation! none of my script are changed!

Comment: Interesting... Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

With Kramdown you could perhaps use
[**comments**](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#extensions)

```
{::comment}
This text is completely ignored by kramdown - a comment in the text.
{:/comment}
```

Comment: well I'm making a "markdown test suite", and I think that this "Kramdown" is something different, but similar to "Markdown", right?